# Callback when App Configuration refreshes

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, configuration, azure-app-configuration

Say I have this code:

```
appConfigOptions.ConfigureRefresh(refresh =>
{
   refresh.Register("Sentinel", "Common", refreshAll: true)
      .SetCacheExpiration(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
});
```

When the Sentinel key changes, is it possible to also invoke a callback/Action, so that we can re-bind the updated configurations into a class?

Basically I want to call the last line of this startup code, again, to refresh `MyAppSettingsClass`:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Configuration.AppConfiguration(configuration);
builder.Services.Configure<MyAppSettingsClass>(configuration);
```

Comment: That approach won't work because your service collection has already been transformed into a service provider at that point anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It should work automatically without you doing anything special. Check out the example in the Azure App Configuration GitHub repo:

https://github.com/Azure/AppConfiguration/blob/main/examples/DotNetCore/WebDemoNet6/WebDemoNet6/Program.cs#L31